# krb5_get_init_creds_opt_set_pkinit in MIT Kerberos?

Tags: c, kerberos

I'm looking for a function like

```
krb5_get_init_creds_opt_set_pkinit
```

that we can find in Heimdal version of Kerberos, to eventually be able to get credentials from smartcard.

But I failed to find the same function in the MIT Kerberos version. It seems this function was removed.

So how the MIT Kerberos has replaced this function ?

Comment: This is an internal function. You should rather use public GSS-API functions. Does it really matter wether the TGT came from a certificate or user/pass?

Comment: Yes it matters because the goal is to authenticate only with the smartcard's certificate, not with a password.

Comment: @Michael-O why you asked this question ?

Comment: Simply don't provide the passwort. MIT Kerberos will try `pkinit` first. See `KRB5_TRACE` output for that.

Comment: @poloDD maybe a little bit late but did you find the solution? I'm trying to find out how kerberos works inside (in part of smart card authentication) but all my efforts are futile